# What's wrong with this code? I can't retrieve data from my database

Tags: vb.net, phpmyadmin

I am just a beginner in databasing and after I used this, it only shows msgbox that says unknown command.

```
Try
    connectionDB.Open()
    cmdDB.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM rescuers WHERE LastName='" & searchres.Text & "';"
    readDB = cmdDB.ExecuteReader()
    With readDB
        .Read()
        rescid.Text = .Item("RescuerID")
        lname.Text = .Item("LastName")
        fname.Text = .Item("FirstName")



        .Close()
    End With
```

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: Can you tell us what you enter in the TextBox `searchres` please?

Comment: everytime I try to retrieve data, it only says "unknown command"

Comment: searchres is a textbox where you can search a certain person's info that is saved in the database.

Comment: It is not a good idea, how you use the text of the TextBox. Try to use parameters to make your query safe against sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the sqlcommand and sqldatareader like so :

```
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM rescuers WHERE LastName='" & searchres.Text & "'", connection)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
```

Post your code for setting up the SqlConnection as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using parameters to avoid SQL injection

```
cmdDB = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM rescuers WHERE LastName = @LastName", DatabaseConnection)

cmdDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", searchres.Text)

readDB = cmdDB.ExecuteReader()
```

this is assuming that you have already defined your reader like this:

```
Dim readDB As SqlDataReader
```

Comment: can I ask what @username is for?

Comment: I think he wanted to write `@LastName` instead of `@Username`.

Comment: oops sorry, I was updating my own code. Thanks Vincent for updating